Replace all "\" with "/" in batch file
I'm starting to learn now about batch file because I need to use it to gather some file path in windows to use with R, the trouble I'm having is
chcp 65001

@echo %~dp0% > root_path.txt

with the above code I can write a txt file with the location of the batch file, but I need to replace all "\" in the path with "/". How I can do it? I tried to do like
chcp 65001

@echo %~dp0:\=/% > root_path.txt

but it doesn't work, I tried to use set and replace but not worked too.

You can't manipulate %0 directly because it's a special variable that doesn't end with a %. If you want to do string manipulation on an argument-style variable, you'll have to store the value in a regular variable first and then manipulate that new variable.
chcp 65001
set "script_path=%~dp0"
>root_path.txt echo %script_path:\=/%

Also, I've moved the >root_path.txt part to the front of the line in case you care about trailing spaces in the content of root_path.txt.

just a quick question if I wished to replace and store the change in script_path, how I could do it?

You can just set the variable to the new value. set "script_path=%script_path:\=/%"
